# sqoop merge-key creating multiple part files instead of one which doesn't serve the purpose of using merge-key

Tags: mysql, hadoop, bigdata, sqoop

Ideally, when we run incremental without `merge-key` it will create new file with the appended data set but if we use `merge-key` then it will create new whole data set including the previous dataset in one file only. But I am not getting one part file when I use `incremental append` in my sqoop job. Below are my steps:

1) Initial data:

```
mysql> select * from departments_per;
+---------------+-----------------+
| department_id | department_name |
+---------------+-----------------+
|             2 | Fitness         |
|             3 | Footwear        |
|             4 | Apparel         |
|             5 | Golf            |
|             6 | Outdoors        |
|             7 | Fan Shop        |
+---------------+-----------------+
```

2) sqoop command to import data into hdfs initially:

```
sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/practice \
--username root \
--password cloudera \
--table departments_per \
--target-dir /departments \
-m 1
```

Now when I see the directory departments under hdfs I can see one part file which is fine.

3) Now I update my initial data in mysql:

```
mysql> select * from departments_demo;
+---------------+-----------------+
| department_id | department_name |
+---------------+-----------------+
|             2 | Fitness         |
|             3 | Footwear        |
|             4 | Apparel         |
|             5 | Golf            |
|             6 | Outdoors        |
|             7 | Fan             |
|             8 | Tushar MC       |
+---------------+-----------------+
```

4) Now I create incremental append job and execute it:

```
sqoop job --create appendJobs12 \
-- import \
--connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/practice \
--username root \
--password cloudera \
--table departments_demo \
-m 1 \
--target-dir /departments \
--incremental append \
--merge-key department_id \
--check-column department_id \
--last-value 0 

sqoop job --exec appendJobs12
```

5) I can see two part files in hdfs directory even though I used `merge-key` concept.

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ hadoop fs -ls /departments
Found 3 items
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera supergroup          0 2018-10-04 00:31 /departments/_SUCCESS
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera supergroup         60 2018-10-04 00:31 /departments/part-m-00000
-rw-r--r--   1 cloudera cloudera           67 2018-10-04 00:37 /departments/part-m-00001
```

When I display data it looks like below:

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ hadoop fs -cat /departments/part-m-00000
2,Fitness
3,Footwear
4,Apparel
5,Golf
6,Outdoors
7,Fan Shop 
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ hadoop fs -cat /departments/part-m-00001
    2,Fitness
    3,Footwear
    4,Apparel
    5,Golf
    6,Outdoors
    7,Fan
    8, Tushar MC
```

where one part file holds the initial data and the second one holds the updated data. Can anybody tell me where am I going wrong because of which I am not able to get one part file with the updated dataset. Thanks in advance

Comment: I find the description of this in the manuals quite confusing .

Comment: Okay. Which part is the confusing so that I can edit it tomorrow

Comment: Earlier the same code was working well but today when I tested it again, it fails . Weird !

Comment: It's the manuals that are a little confusing. Have a look here https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html#_literal_sqoop_merge_literal

Comment: Yeah I read it already . There they have mentioned merge tool for merging old and new dataset

Comment: Please can you test it on your machine with your knowledge

Comment: See https://dzone.com/articles/hive-incremental-update-using-sqoop

Comment: Okay I don't think so it would help me but still I will try it first and ll keep u updated

Comment: Okay I don't think so it would help me but still I will try it first and ll keep u updated

Comment: Okay I don't think so it would help me but still I will try it first and ll keep u updated

Comment: Can you post content of both files please using cat or more

Comment: Interesting. I get your idea but I think you need to do as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47407314/sqoop-incremental-import-append-mode-with-timestamp-column which uses timestamp as well. You seem  to compare to the same value, which may produce unexpected results.

Comment: Can you show contents of your 2 files please?

Comment: hello, I have updated my question.

Comment: OK, that is as I suspect, and it is odd. The documentation for updating data in Hive is a little hard to follow and is not really a goer. That last thing I sent I think is the way to do it, I will check later today. Can you check via Hue that you get to see the data twice pls?

Comment: If you use incremental append without merge-key then it will create new part file which I already know and the same thing is mentioned in that post as well. Sure just let me know once figure out some solution for my problem. Thank you so much for your time :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181316/discussion-between-thebluephantom-and-debuggerr).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I researched this and got the same error with your approach. So, it is not correct - reading the various stuff I have to say I think it is not so clear. Anyway.

I get the impression that external tables and some LINUX scripting is required with intermediate target directories.

So, 1) I added the data in mysql and 2) did a sqoop import followed by 3) an update in mysql followed by 4) another incremental import as you did which is not really correct I think but you are wanting updates so OK, followed by 5) codegen and lastly 6) sqoop MERGE.

These are the main steps:

Initial import

```
sqoop import -m 1 --connect jdbc:mysql://quickstart:3306/retail_db --username=retail_dba --password=cloudera --table ged  --warehouse-dir=/user/hive/warehouse --create-hive-table --hive-import --fields-terminated-by ',' --hive-drop-import-delims
```

Incremental load as you did

```
sqoop import -m 1 --connect jdbc:mysql://quickstart:3306/retail_db --username=retail_dba --password=cloudera --table ged  --warehouse-dir=/user/hive/warehouse --fields-terminated-by ',' --hive-drop-import-delims --last-value 0 --merge-key id --incremental append --check-column id
```

Codegen

```
 sqoop codegen --connect jdbc:mysql://quickstart:3306/retail_db --username=retail_dba --password=cloudera --table ged
```

Merge

```
 sqoop merge --new-data /user/hive/warehouse/ged --onto /user/hive/warehouse/new_ged --merge-key id --target-dir /user/hive/merged/ged2 --jar-file /tmp/sqoop-cloudera/compile/c8d374075351d228c50d89354959762e/ged.jar -class-name ged
```

Results: 
    [cloudera@quickstart ~]$ hadoop fs -cat /user/hive/merged/ged2/*
    1,YYY
    2,Peter
    3,Bobby
    4,Maria
    5,Joke
    6,Joker

whereby I originally had 1, XXX but not 6,Joker

This is somewhat different, so I am not sure what to state. In any event 1 file is not a valid assumption with lots of data. Your statement may work with extra parameters but this works as well.

The clue here is updating of immutable systems via merge requiring different targets that can be switched via external table commands in terms of locations.

Comment: Yeah, using merge tool I was able to combine two datasets.

Comment: Lol ! Thanks . Appreciate your efforts as well

Comment: can you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52906895/how-to-join-3-tables-in-spark-rdd/52906998#52906998

Comment: Will look tomorrow

Comment: Okay np . Whenever you get time

Answer (score 0):

There is always good time to Answer and it is Never Late !!!
Just refreshing my memories and Hope you will get it .

I can see many things in the above incremental import sqoop command :

1. The merge key concept was introduced only for "lastmodified" incremental load type , so that the updated record can be taken care- But above requirement  is used for append mode.
   *Always In append mode, New mapper partition file is created:
   /departments/part-**m**-00000
   /departments/part-**m**-00001
2. To get in one part file- use lastmodified" incremental load only.
3. merge-key is not recommended to run through the sqoop jobs-technically command will work BUT main objective of merge-key will not be fulfilled.
   4)This is only place -where in sqoop command , reducer process is invoked.
   /departments/part-**r**-00000   ( r -reducer ) ---> if the merge-key is ran for lastmodified incremental load.

sqoop import 
--connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/practice 
--username root 
--password cloudera 
--table departments_demo 
--m 1 
--target-dir /departments 
--incremental lastmodified\  ===>changes made
--merge-key department_id \
--check-column \ ==>ONLY date and timestamp datatype is allowed
--last-value 0