# How to JOIN 3 RDD's using Spark Scala

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql, bigdata, rdd

I want to join `3 tables` using `spark rdd`. I achieved my objective using spark sql but when I tried to join it using Rdd I am not getting the desired results. Below is my query using `spark SQL` and the `output`:

```
scala> actorDF.as("df1").join(movieCastDF.as("df2"),$"df1.act_id"===$"df2.act_id").join(movieDF.as("df3"),$"df2.mov_id"===$"df3.mov_id").
filter(col("df3.mov_title")==="Annie Hall").select($"df1.act_fname",$"df1.act_lname",$"df2.role").show(false)
+---------+---------+-----------+                                               
|act_fname|act_lname|role       |
+---------+---------+-----------+
|Woody    |Allen    |Alvy Singer|
+---------+---------+-----------+
```

Now I created the `pairedRDDs` for three datasets and it is as below :

```
scala> val actPairedRdd=actRdd.map(_.split("\t",-1)).map(p=>(p(0),(p(1),p(2),p(3))))

scala> actPairedRdd.take(5).foreach(println)

(101,(James,Stewart,M))
(102,(Deborah,Kerr,F))
(103,(Peter,OToole,M))
(104,(Robert,De Niro,M))
(105,(F. Murray,Abraham,M))

scala> val movieCastPairedRdd=movieCastRdd.map(_.split("\t",-1)).map(p=>(p(0),(p(1),p(2))))
movieCastPairedRdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, (String, String))] = MapPartitionsRDD[318] at map at <console>:29

scala> movieCastPairedRdd.foreach(println)
(101,(901,John Scottie Ferguson))
(102,(902,Miss Giddens))
(103,(903,T.E. Lawrence))
(104,(904,Michael))
(105,(905,Antonio Salieri))
(106,(906,Rick Deckard))


scala> val moviePairedRdd=movieRdd.map(_.split("\t",-1)).map(p=>(p(0),(p(1),p(2),p(3),p(4),p(5),p(6))))
moviePairedRdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, (String, String, String, String, String, String))] = MapPartitionsRDD[322] at map at <console>:29

scala> moviePairedRdd.take(2).foreach(println)
(901,(Vertigo,1958,128,English,1958-08-24,UK))
(902,(The Innocents,1961,100,English,1962-02-19,SW))
```

Here `actPairedRdd` and `movieCastPairedRdd` is linked with each other and `movieCastPairedRdd` and `moviePairedRdd` is linked since they have common column.
Now when I join all the three datasets I am not getting any data

```
scala> actPairedRdd.join(movieCastPairedRdd).join(moviePairedRdd).take(2).foreach(println)
```

I am getting blank records. So where am I going wrong ?? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JOINs like this with RDDs are painful, that's another reason why DFs are nicer.

You get no data as the pair RDD = K, V has no common data for the K part of the last RDD. The K's with 101, 102 will join, but there is no commonality with the 901, 902. You need to shift things around, like this, my more limited example:

```
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Seq(
           (101,("James","Stewart","M")),
           (102,("Deborah","Kerr","F")),
           (103,("Peter","OToole","M")),
           (104,("Robert","De Niro","M")) 
           ))

val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(Seq(
           (101,(901,"John Scottie Ferguson")),
           (102,(902,"Miss Giddens")),
           (103,(903,"T.E. Lawrence")),
           (104,(904,"Michael"))
           ))

val rdd3 = sc.parallelize(Seq(
          (901,("Vertigo",1958 )),
          (902,("The Innocents",1961)) 
          ))

val rdd4 = rdd1.join(rdd2)

val new_rdd4 = rdd4.keyBy(x => x._2._2._1)  // Redefine Key for join with rdd3
val rdd5 = rdd3.join(new_rdd4)
rdd5.collect
```

returns:

```
res14: Array[(Int, ((String, Int), (Int, ((String, String, String), (Int, String)))))] = Array((901,((Vertigo,1958),(101,((James,Stewart,M),(901,John Scottie Ferguson))))), (902,((The Innocents,1961),(102,((Deborah,Kerr,F),(902,Miss Giddens))))))
```

You will need to strip out the data via a map, I leave that to you. INNER join per default.

Comment: Yeah , Thanks @thebluephantom. You made my day. I know this is much simpler with DFs but I wanted to figure out how it could be done using RDDs as well.

Comment: can you help me with the this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53150584/how-to-get-the-specified-output-without-combinebykey-and-aggregatebykey-in-spark