# How to get the specified output without combineByKey and aggregateByKey in spark RDD

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, bigdata, rdd

Below is my data:

```
val keysWithValuesList = Array("foo=A", "foo=A", "foo=A", "foo=A", "foo=B", bar=C","bar=D", "bar=D")
```

Now I want below types of output but **without** using `combineByKey` and `aggregateByKey`:

```
1) Array[(String, Int)] = Array((foo,5), (bar,3))  
2) Array((foo,Set(B, A)),
(bar,Set(C, D)))
```

Below is my attempt:

```
scala> val keysWithValuesList = Array("foo=A", "foo=A", "foo=A", "foo=A", "foo=B", "bar=C",
     | "bar=D", "bar=D")  
scala> val sample=keysWithValuesList.map(_.split("=")).map(p=>(p(0),(p(1))))
sample: Array[(String, String)] = Array((foo,A), (foo,A), (foo,A), (foo,A), (foo,B), (bar,C), (bar,D), (bar,D))
```

Now when I type the variable name followed by tab to see the applicable methods for the mapped RDD I can see the below options out of which none can satisfy my requirement:

```
scala> sample.
apply          asInstanceOf   clone          isInstanceOf   length         toString       update
```

So how can I achieve this ??

Comment: You seem to be using an `Array` and not an `RDD`. To solve this for an `RDD` in Spark it would be required to do some kind of groupby+aggregation, e.g. use `aggregateByKey`.

Comment: Not sure I follow here.

Comment: I don't want to use aggregateByKey or combineByKey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a standard approach.

Point to note: you need to be working with an RDD. I think that is the bottleneck.

Here you go:

```
val keysWithValuesList = Array("foo=A", "foo=A", "foo=A", "foo=A", "foo=B", "bar=C","bar=D", "bar=D") 

val sample=keysWithValuesList.map(_.split("=")).map(p=>(p(0),(p(1))))

val sample2 = sc.parallelize(sample.map(x => (x._1, 1)))
val sample3 = sample2.reduceByKey(_+_) 
sample3.collect()

val sample4 = sc.parallelize(sample.map(x => (x._1, x._2))).groupByKey()   
sample4.collect()

val sample5 = sample4.map(x => (x._1, x._2.toSet))
sample5.collect()
```