# How to update the records in hive table using PySpark?

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql

We are using spark to process large data and recently got new use case where we need to update the data in Hive table using spark.

Below is the simple example:
Data resides in Hive table and the application reads into data frame (say df1) using PySpark.
Ex: data frame has below columns.

**EmpNo Name Age Salary**

1    aaaa   28  30000

2    bbbb   38  20000

3    cccc   26  25000

4    dddd   30  32000

Need to add more records to the table using spark.

Ex:

**Action EmpNo Name Age Salary**

*Add*     5    dddd 30 32000

Application can read new data into second data frame (say df2) by stripping of Action column and append to the table. It is straight forward and it works perfectly fine.

df.write.format('parquet') \
            .mode('append') \
            .saveAsTable(canonical_hive_table)

In some cases, we need to delete existing records or update them based on the Action column.

Ex:

**Action EmpNo Name Age Salary**

*Delete*   2   bbbb  38  20000

*Update*   4   dddd  30  42000

In above example, application need to Delete EmpNo:2 and update EmpNo:4.

Final output should look like this:

**EmpNo Name Age Salary**

1    aaaa   28  30000

3    cccc   26  25000

4    dddd   30  42000

5    dddd   30  32000

As I understand, update operation is not available in Spark Sql and also, the dataframe is immutable and can't change the records.

Does anyone come across the situation? or aware of any option to update existing records in Hive table using PySpark?

Pls: Application need to deal with thousands of updates regularly on millions of records.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to perform and UPSERT (INSERT + UPDATE)using Hive on your daily incremental loads? If thats the case its a daily overwrite. We might need a little bit more than the logic here to draft out a solution.

Comment: How did you go here?

Answer (score 0):

As in most things you need to use the right tools and approach - and be cognizant of any limitatios; Hadoop is by and large immutable.

Data Frames can save in different modes but cannot selectively update records -pyspark or scala or R or JAVA have nothing to do with it, with the exception of Cloudera's KUDU Storage manager which has a Spark Connector that the DF Writer can use, but there were when I last used this, security limitations that the adminstrators do not like.

What can you do?

1. Use **KUDU** which is mutable - but I suspect not an option. It is like PARQUET - columnar and the performance is on par from my experience.
2. Use your DF's or not, and use **ORC** files instead of PARQUET for persistence which are also columnar and can be updated with Hive's MERGE statement in a script or Spark SQL with Hive Support enabled. This option implies forget PARQUET. This link gives some interesting insights: https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-differences-between-ORC-Avro-and-Parquet-File-Formats-in-Hadoop-in-terms-of-compression-and-speed
3. Do your thing in DF's and what not and **re-state** (i.e. write) all data (again) and write to one of 2 versions of a PARQUET table / directory, partitioned or not, and add a view layer to switch between current and new version views. This was done when ORC was not used.

With MERGE, one can compact small Hadoop Hive files within partitions, but only if the format is ORC - if memory serves correctly. I am going to have to refresh my memory here, may be it has changed in newer versions and API's.

Moreover:

1. So, you have a few options and one need not do it all in SPARK with DF's.
2. Databricks has DELTA tables for this type of stuff as well.
3. You can use sqoop in akward fashion with external tables to get newer data if you are using JDBC imports from RDBMS.s, but I cannot tell that from the question. Here is the logic: [sqoop merge-key creating multiple part files instead of one which doesn't serve the purpose of using merge-key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52641463/sqoop-merge-key-creating-multiple-part-files-instead-of-one-which-doesnt-serve)

A few things to think about. Good luck.

Comment: Great Thanks for these pointers. They are helpful and need to drill into some options and decide the way forward.